# Excel Cell Formatting Special Case

Tags: excel, file, csv, hyperlink, formatting

I have an interesting dilema and was wondering if someone might know if this is possible. I'm creating a .csv file using java and for one of the comma separated entries for each row is a url.

**Example:**

item1,item2,item3,http://myurl.com

Originally when I loaded the .csv file in Excel, it loaded just the text for the url and wasn't making it clickable. I was able to solve this by just surrounding the entry with this string while creating the file:

**=HYPERLINK("http://myurl.com")**

When Excel loads, the link is clickable and the mouse pointer changes to the hand icon. The only problem is that when you are just looking at it and not hovering the cell, it just looks like black text on a white background. Usually when you see a link, it is blue with an underline signifying that it is clickable. I would like to have this visual queue, but I am not sure if there is a way of doing it just by modifying my function above with some sort of cell formatting function or something.

And Yes, I know what conditional formatting is and how to apply it to a cell in Excel. However, this will not work for me, because I just need it to work when the file is loaded. The file is always created new when a user downloads it, because the contents are always changing. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is creating the file in another format instead of CSV an option (like maybe HTML or XML)?

Comment: Not in this case. The people that download the file will need it in csv format so they can import into multiple programs including Excel.

Comment: You can import HTML or XML into Excel.  Are you saying that there are other programs that your users need to import the data into, but these don't support HTML or XML?

Comment: If I add the html to the csv for the one entry will it work?

Comment: No, I think you need to create the whole file as an HTML file (complete with <html>, <body>, <table>, <tr>, and <td> tags).  If that's an option, post back, and I'll submit an answer with some more details.

Comment: If I could do it in the csv entry itself that would have worked, but that solution won't work for me. It needs to be a csv file.

Comment: You mean, you need a CSV file to do ALL THE JOB?? Or are other options as VBA and other languages permitted?

Comment: Just CSV, nothing else.

Comment: Could you have a custom import function in the end users Excel ? so rather than just opening the CSV in Excel they open using your own load function that does the formatting ?

Answer (score 1):

The reason that hyperlinks entered by double-clicking a .csv file are "cold" (not clickable) is that the part of the UI that make a "hot" hyperlink out of typed text has been by-passed.  If the .csv has raw URLs rather than =HYPERLINK() functions, they can be made hot by running the following:

```
Sub HyperIgniter()
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If Left(r.Text, 4) = "http" Then
            r.Select
            Application.SendKeys "{F2}"
            Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
            DoEvents
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

This is the equivalent of re-typing each of the hyperlinks, thus making them "hot" and giving them the usual format.

Comment: The problem is he's sending the CSV out so the recipients won't be running or even receiving any macros.

Answer (score 1):

You can create templated excel files using [jXLS](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/) library. it is really easy to use. [Sample](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/samples/tagsample.html)

Answer (score 1):

This can absolutely be done but it might be more complicated than you expected.

first, you will have to follow the steps found in this post to create a new Custom Number Format which you can use in all new workbooks and so will your customers.

[Adding cell format options to Custom list](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/adding-cell-format-options-to-custom-list/cdb581a5-16f1-4f9c-ada3-db3299ef023c)

I would quote the list but I'd rather not take any credit for HansV's great solution.

The option that you want to add will be "[blue]General"

Now, your CSV file should be saving the string like the below example:
"=text(hyperlink(""http://www.google.com""),""[blue]General"")"

So, now you are applying the new format (which controls font color). Just replace google.com with your URL. You will notice that there are many quotations as a product of the tricky formatting CSV forces so that it will add quotes where needed as well as not splitting the necessary comma (for the TEXT function) into two cells.